# Using C, why would a char * type be of size 2 in one place, but 4 in another?

Tags: c

From a question on the [Practice C test](http://www.geekinterview.com/quiz/C-Practice-Test.html) from GeekInterview, why is the size of `ptr1` 2, while `ptr2` and `ptr3` are size of 4?

```
main() 
{ 
char near * near *ptr1; 
char near * far *ptr2; 
char near * huge *ptr3; 
printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(ptr1),sizeof(ptr2),sizeof(ptr3)); 
}
```

Output: 2 4 4

Comment: Wow, near and far pointers. Those were the days. Is anyone still using this, or is it just an outdated test?

Comment: This is pretty outdated, but I bet this is still relevant on some embedded systems...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When working on architectures with segmented memory (like x86 real mode), one can distinguish three types of pointer addresses (examples for x86 in segment:offset notation):

- **near**

  Only stores the offset part (which is 16-bit) - when resolving such a pointer, the current data segment offset will be used as segment address.
- **far**

  Stores segment and offset address (16 bit each), thus defining an absolute physical address in memory.
- **huge**

  Same as far pointer, but can be normalized, i.e. `0000:FFFF + 1` will be wrapped around appropriately to the next segment address.

On modern OSes this doesn't matter any more as the memory model is usually flat, using virtual memory instead of addressing physical memory directly (at least in ring 3 applications).

Comment: x86 protected mode still supports segmentation.

Comment: @caf: Yes, but I chose real mode as the better example because in real mode all applications will have to deal with segmented addresses.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're using near pointers vs. [far pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer).  A far pointer requires two 16 bit addresses, in this case.

(The "huge" specifier is a non-standard far pointer syntax, for handling some specific far pointer cases...)

Comment: Awesome, I'll research `near` and `far` pointers to get a better understanding.

Comment: @Nick: I wouldn't bother. It's quite archaic.

Comment: @Novelocrat A friend of mine said the test is Borland C, and some of the questions aren't very well thought out.

Comment: `near` and `far` are non-standard too.